# Optimal number of clusters for variables clustering

Tags: r, clustering

First of all, I know that this question has been addressed a certain number of times, but I didn't find an answer concerning the **clustering of variables**, instead of observations.

Concretely, I am using the function `varclus` from the package `Hmisc` to perform variables clustering.

As an example, I want to perform a cluster analysis on the variables of the dataset `ionosphere` (available in the package `dprep`).

My code is as follow :

```
> library(Hmisc) 
> library(dprep) 
> data(ionosphere) 
> iono_min_l_col <- ionosphere[-length(ionosphere)] 
> iono_mx_min_l_col <- data.matrix(iono_min_l_col) 
> iono_clus <- varclus(iono_mx_min_l_col)
> plot(iono_clus)
```

When using `plot()` I get the following dendrogram :

[image]

However, I don't know in how many clusters I should group my variables.
I can used the following code to know in which cluster are my variables (e.g. V1 Cluster 1, V2 Cluster 3, etc...), but I don't know **how to get the optimal number of clusters** ? (i.e. ***k*** in the following code)

```
> groups <- cutree(varclus(iono_mx_min_l_col)$hclust, k= ***???***)
```

Does someone know how to get this optimal number, ***k*** ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: To rephrase to see if I have well understood, you have N variables, and for each of these N variables you have T observations, is that right? Then, you cluster the N variables based on the Spearman correlation of their T observations computed pairwise between the variables? If so, I may have a possible answer.

Comment: That is right. The ionosphere dataset contains 351 observations (=T) and 32 independent variables (=N). I don't really know how the Spearman correlation works but I suppose it is just as you said. So yes, you understood well my question! I'm really interested to hear what you have in mind! Thanks

Comment: oh! I just realized that I really did miss the point, and have not understood correctly your question then. You have only 32 variables $N$ that you know independent?! So, why do you need to cluster them? using correlation?

Comment: They are called independent variables (or predictor), in comparison with the dependent variables (which is the class variable). I need to cluster them to know which of them bring more or less the same information, so that I can group them in clusters.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful when using correlation, it should be applied on [*stationary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_process) variables, otherwise you will measure spurious correlation. I can give you a detailed answer tomorrow if you don't mind, time to sleep now after a rough day at work... But basically, I suggest to use the idea of [bootstrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(statistics)), i.e. you perturb your observations by sampling from them with replacement.
You create $L$ of such perturbed dataset (somewhat similar copies) and then you apply your clustering for $K=2..N-1$ and evaluate for each $K$ how similar are the results (with an [Adjusted Rand Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rand_index#Adjusted_Rand_index) for example). The rationale is that if there were some real underlying clustering structure of correlation, it should be persistent to small statistical noise. Thus, the better score for the real number of clusters $K$. I use that in practice on stocks and other financial products. It works quite well for detecting the macro level.

For example, you can use something similar to the code below. I also evaluate the stability on the pure noise samples to check for bias in the evaluation. Then, you can plot the stability scores and the noise scores, and have an idea of the number of clusters you may have in your data.

```
#load data
data,names,dates = read_data()          

#create the bootstrap samples
obj_samples = create_bootsamples(data,names)

#create the noise samples
noise_samples = create_noise_samples(len(data),len(data[0]))

nbClust_min = 2
nbClust_max = round(len(names)/3)
nb_clusters = [i for i in range(nbClust_min,nbClust_max+1)]

stability_scores = []; noise_scores = []
for K in nb_clusters:
    print("nbCluster: "+str(K)+" / "+str(nbClust_max))
    for cur_sample in obj_samples:
        cur_sample["K"] = K
    for cur_noise in noise_samples:
        cur_noise["K"] = K
    #data processing    
    boot_labels = Parallel(n_jobs=-2,verbose=5) (delayed(compute_clustering)(cur_sample) for cur_sample in obj_samples)
    stability_scores.append(evaluate_stability(boot_labels))
    #noise processing
    noise_labels = Parallel(n_jobs=-2,verbose=5) (delayed(compute_clustering)(cur_noise) for cur_noise in noise_samples)
    noise_scores.append(evaluate_stability(noise_labels))
```

And, I will get:
[image]
which indicates me that there is a first level with 2 clusters, then 7 clusters, then it is approximately the same whatever the number of clusters. This makes sense knowning the data on which it was computing on :)

Nonetheless, be careful clustering may be quite slow to converge and it depends on

- the clustering methodology chosen,
- obviously, the correlation coefficient that you have chosen which converges more or less quickly,
- the complexity of your data:

  - how many real clusters are in your variables?
  - is there a hierarchy of clusters?
  - is the contrast between clusters strong?

To understand how it may impact your results, consider this simple experiments.
Build a distance/correlation matrix which is 'neat'. Clusters are obvious and thus the matrix is block diagonal. Then, sample from this matrix (using a simple multivariate Gaussian if you want). Then, you can estimate how much data/realizations you may need to recover the underlying clusters. You may be surprised :) Remember that here you have assumed a very-neat situation and you have stationary (even i.i.d.) observations from a Gaussian, so the ideal case that never happens in practice! You can complexify the model with respect to your understanding of the data.

For example, with a Single Linkage clustering, you may get:
[image]

But with Ward:
[image]

If you are interested by that topic, you can have a look at [this paper.](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1603.04017v1.pdf)

Comment: Thanks I will take a look at that. I'm interested in the detailed answer as well! Thanks again